# Share image taking from Camera

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I am developing an app which takes a picture with the camera and allows the user to share it. But the share intent isn't working. I have checked but none are working on my device. I am running the app on an Android 6.0 marshmallow tablet.

Here is my code

```
public class SharePic extends Activity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView picView;
Button shareBtn;
Bitmap imageBitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_pic);
    picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picView);
    shareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    }
    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        picView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}


public void share(View view){
    String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageBitmap,"title", null);
    Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So, when is the share button being called.
I guess you might have to set event listener `setOnClickListener` on share button click in case you haven't set it in the XML

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                share(v);
            }
        });
```